# How UDP Socket handle the diff host

Tags: tcp, udp

Suppose a process in Host C has a UDP socket with port number 6789. Suppose
both Host A and Host B each send a UDP segment to Host C with destination
port number 6789. Will both of these segments be directed to the same
socket at Host C? If so, how will the process at Host C know that these two
segments originated from two different hosts?

Solution Provided by book is as follows

> Yes, both segments will be directed to the same socket. For each
> received segment, at the socket interface, the operating system will
> provide the process with the IP addresses to determine the origins of
> the individual segments.

1. i don't get the solution can anyone elaborate it ?
2. What can be the answer if the word "UDP" is changed by "TCP" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will both of these segments be directed to the same socket at Host C?

If the socket on host C is not explicitly connected, then both the packet from host A and the packet from host B will arrive at this socket.

> If so, how will the process at Host C know that these two segments originated from two different hosts?

Using [recvfrom](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) the client not only gets the packet payload but also the sender of the packet.

> What can be the answer if the word "UDP" is changed by "TCP" ?

TCP has the concept of a connection, which involves the explicit creation of a connection, data transfer and explicit connection tear down. A and B each must create a connection to C first before they can transfer data. To make this possible C must first  [listen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) on the bound server socket and then can [accept](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) a new connection. `accept` will return a new socket which is used for the data transfer. It will also return the clients source IP and port (i.e. A or B) so that C knows which client is associated with the new connection. This can also be later checked on the accepted socket with [getpeername](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html).